# SetDataSource on CRViewer in vb6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I want to make a report on crviewer in vb6 and database access.
then display the data based on the query criteria.
the code that I made did not experience an error. but the data that appears does not affect the query that I created. or data displayed everything.

The following code that I created.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
koneksi
Dim oapp As CRAXDDRT.Application
Dim oreport As CRAXDDRT.Report
strSQL = "select * from kelas where kode_kelas = " & "'" + Combo1.Text &    "'" + ""
Set rs = New Recordset
rs.Open strSQL, db, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Set oapp = New CRAXDDRT.Application
Set oreport = oapp.OpenReport(App.Path & "\report1.rpt", 1)
oreport.Database.SetDataSource rs, 3, 1
CRViewer1.ReportSource = oreport
CRViewer1.ViewReport
End Sub
```

crystal report 8.6, vb6 and database access.
please help me, or corrected my code.
thanks...